# Building a JavaScript library, why use an IIFE this way?

Tags: javascript, amd, umd, module-export

I have noticed a lot of libraries use this style below to define their library. I also notice that the first self invoking function has something to do with Require.js or AMD systems, they always have factory as an argument, I will look more into Require.js, always been into Browserify.

Why is the main code passed into the end of the first self invoking function inside parentheses, is this is a closure, or just considered an anonymous function, I will dig deeper into both. What are the benefits to this? It looks like inside the closure the author passes a `string`, `this`, and a `callback`.

Will this give my library a clean safe way to globalize the main object in this example below `Please`?

```
(function( globalName, root, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define( [], factory );
    }
    else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
        module.exports = factory();
    }
    else{
        root[globalName] = factory();
    }
}('Please', this, function(){
```

I am trying to dig really deep into JavaScript and create my own small MVC architecture, I don't want to hear I am silly or its been done before, I want to challenge myself and learn.

If there are any great resources for creating a JavaScript library or even better an MVC library I would love to know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code pattern is called [Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) (UMD). It allows you to make your JavaScript library usable in different environments. It provides three ways of defining modules:

1. [Asynchronous Module Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) (AMD), implemented by [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [Dojo Toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/).

   `define( [], factory );`
2. [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) — NodeJS modules.

   `module.exports = factory();`
3. Assigning module to the global object, for example `window` in browsers.

   `root[globalName] = factory();`

The IIFE has three parameters: `globalName`, `root` and `factory`.

- `globalName` is the name of your module. It applies only to the third way of defining a module, i.e. assigning your module object to the global variable. For example, if you set this parameter to `"myAwesomeModule"` and use the code in browser (without AMD), you can access your module using `myAwesomeModule` variable.
- `root` is the name of global object. Obviously, it also applies only to the third way of defining a module. Usually `this` is passed as this parameter, because `this` is a reference to `window` in browser. However, this [doesn't work in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012589/umd-javascript-module-which-also-works-in-strict-mode). If you want your code to work in strict mode, you can replace `this` with `typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : undefined`.
- Finally, `factory` is an anonymous function, which should return your module as object.

See also:

- [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)
- [What Is AMD, CommonJS, and UMD?](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/)

Answer (score 11):

This is an example of [Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) (UMD). It is a technique to make a JS module compatible with the three popular JS module specs:

1. [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) (AMD, used by Require.js)

   ```
   define('name', [ /* dependencies */ ], factory);
   ```
2. [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) (Node.js ecosystem)

   ```
   module.exports = object;
   ```
3. Global exports (for example, on `window` in the browser)

   ```
   global['name'] = object;
   ```

UMD wraps a *factory function* responsible for creating the object to be exported and passes it as an argument to an *immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE), as in the snippet you pasted. The IIFE is responsible for detecting the module environment, and exporting the object created by the factory in an appropriate way. The pattern is as follows:

```
(function (name, root, factory) {
   // detect the module environment and
   // export the result of factory()
})('name', this, function () {
   // module code
   // return the object to be exported
});
```

Many transpilers and build tools generate this wrapper automatically.