# How to add ES2015 import support to regular packages with self invoking methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

The package [smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) does not support ES2015 import.
I want to offer a pull request with support for import.

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) I need to add the following line:

```
export default smoothScrollFunction;
```

However the package start with a self-invoking method and I am not sure how to proceed? How do you export a self invoking method?

code:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define([], factory(root));
    } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
        module.exports = factory(root);
    } else {
        root.smoothScroll = factory(root);
    }
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, (function (root) {

    'use strict';

    //
    // more code...
    //
```

Comment: This code pattern is called Universal Module Definition (UMD), see [Building a JavaScript library, why use an IIFE this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34866603/3853934).

Comment: Does it mean it's ES2015 import ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES2015 import/export statements require transpilation as no environment currently supports them. When transpiled they will be transformed into something that *is* supported by the target environment. If your target is Node this means that `export` statements would become `module.exports = ...`, or if your target is the browser then your modules will likely be bundled and wrapped in such a way that they are `require`-able, e.g. as in Browserify and Webpack.

> Does it mean it's ES2015 import ready?

Practically, yes. Modules do not need to use the `import`/`export` in order to be ES2015 import friendly because actually no environment is, we just transform the import/export syntax in a way that makes it compatible.

In particular, with the module you have shared, you can `import smoothScrollFunction from 'smooth-scroll'` without the module itself containing an `export smoothScrollFunction` statement, as your import statement will be transpiled to (something like) `var smoothScrollFunction = require('smooth-scroll')` anyway.

Having said all this, in order to address the question in its entirety, you would amend an IIFE<sup>1</sup> to be strictly ES2015 import compatible by removing the IIFE altogether, as ES2015 modules are standalone and have their own scope, much like modules in Node. You would however be dropping support for browsers, which undermines the purpose of using the IIFE / UMD<sup>2</sup> approach.

For example (remember that this is not actually necessary!), we would take whatever the return value of the `factory` function is, along with anything that occurs before it, and move this out of the factory function. We would then `export default` the return value of the factory function.

```
// Anything before the return statement 
// in the factory function goes here

export default // Return value of factory function goes here
```

---

<sup>1</sup>IIFE: [immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

<sup>2</sup>UMD: [universal module declaration](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/)

Comment: You could however transpile `export` declaration back to UMD using a build tool such as rollup